# Can I join the output of a loop with Liquid?

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I'm looking to output something like:
`data-tags="[tag1, tag2, tag3]"` but instead, I'm getting `data-tags:[tag1tag2tag3]`. Am I using join incorrectly?

Code:

```
data-tags="{% for tag in subtask.tags %}{{tag.title | slugify | join ', '}}{% endfor %}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`data-tags="{% for tag in subtask.tags %}{{ tag.title | slugify }}{% unless forloop.last %}, {% endunless %}{% endfor %}">`

If you didn't need to `slugify` the title you could do:

```
{% assign tags = subtask.tags | map: title %}
<div data-tags="{{ tags | join: ', ' }}">
```

This is because the join filter can only be applied to an array not the value of the array.